# Use php variable in an other php file

Tags: php

I am using phpMyAdmin for collecting data
I have extracted the data in the format of a PHP Array
Now I would like to extract the data in the PHP array in order to put them in a text file.
I suppose I have to do this in another PHP file
I was wondering how can I access the array of the first file ?

Comment: What is your current code for retrieving the data? It depends how you retired the data and what methods you're using? mysql, mysqli, PDO?

Comment: phpmyadmin panel > click table > export > export as text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you can use includes. When you include the file the variable scopes will continue into the file.

***index.php***

```
<?php    
$array = [1,2,3,4]
include('my_file.php');
?>
```

**my_file.php**

```
<?php
print_r($array);
?>
```

Documentation:
***http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php***

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php file you used to retrieve the data. Ther's no need to code this in another file.

If you want to store an array into a file, I would suggest you to encode this in some sort of string with json_encode() or serialize(). You can then recover your array using json_decode() and unserialize()

Answer (score 0):

Lets call the file which contains your PHP array `data_array.php`

```
<?php
    $data_array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
?>
```

Then in the PHP file where you want to use your data.

```
<?php
   require_once("data_array.php");
   print_r($data_array);
?>
```

We included the `data_array.php` file and printed the `$data_array` array variable from the `data_array.php` file.

Though I would suggest you to learn to use SQL client like PDO itself in PHP so you do not have to manually fetch the data with phpMyAdmin.